# curly curly Error: Base operators are not defined for quosures

Tags: r, rlang

The following custom function worked before, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320453/insert-if-statement-after-pipe-to-return-error-message-within-custom-functio), but it doesn't seem to work anymore:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
library(scales)
data1 <- data.frame(date1 = sample(seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date('2018-01-01'), by="day"), 5),
                    num1 = 1:5)
data1
hist_date_f <- function(df, date_varaible) {
    df %>%
      group_by(month = floor_date({{date_varaible}}, "month")) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(freq = n()) %>%  
      ggplot(aes(x = month, y = freq)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
      scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m-%Y"), 
                   breaks = date_breaks ("1 month")) + 
      theme_bw()
}

hist_date_f(data1, date1)
# Error: Base operators are not defined for quosures.
# Do you need to unquote the quosure?

#   # Bad:
#   myquosure == rhs

#   # Good:
#   !!myquosure == rhs
```

There must be some update since that solution causing the issue. I'm trying to avoid `enquo()` and `!!` with `{{ }}`.

```
sessionInfo()
# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

# other attached packages:
#  [1] scales_1.1.1    rlang_0.4.10    forcats_0.5.0   stringr_1.4.0  
#  [5] dplyr_1.0.3     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.2    
#  [9] tibble_3.0.5    ggplot2_3.3.3   tidyverse_1.3.0 tidylog_1.0.2
```

thanks

**EDIT** this is a reported bug with `dplyr` [bug](http://bug%20github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/959)

Comment: Not sure what is going on but maybe related to `group_by()`. If you create the "month" variable in `mutate()` and then group instead of  using `group_by()` directly things seem to work: `mutate(month = floor_date({{date_varaible}}, "month")) %>% group_by(month) %>% ...`

Comment: @aosmith bug https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/959

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
hist_date_f <- function(df, date_varaible) {
   df %>%
    group_by(month = floor_date(!! ensym(date_varaible), "month")) %>%
    dplyr::summarize(freq = n()) %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x = month, y = freq)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
   scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m-%Y"), 
               breaks = date_breaks ("1 month")) + 
  theme_bw()
 }
```

-testing

```
hist_date_f(data1, date1)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, do you know why `{{}}` is no longer working though, I thought it was designed for this specific type of task?

Comment: @user63230 I think there is a clash with `lubridate` function `floor_date` because `group_by(month = month({{date_varaible}})) }` this works

Comment: @user63230 it would be a bug.  Can you raise an issue in their github page

Comment: it was a bug https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/959